# Build meteor app in custom GitLab hook

Tags: git, gitlab, hook, meteor

How do I build a meteor app (do 'meteor build .') in a GitLab custom hook? The custom hook is run by the user git who does not seem to have any possibility to run meteor build.

Therefore I want to change the user in the script to someone who is known to be able to build the app.

This is my bash file until now:

```
#!/bin/sh
#

# The deployed directory
DEPLOYDIR=/var/www/site/

echo " - Starting checkout"
GIT_WORK_TREE="$DEPLOYDIR" git checkout -f
echo " - Finished checkout" 

echo " - Starting meteor build"
#not working yet
sudo su - nodejs
cd "$DEPLOYDIR"
meteor build .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`su - user` starts an *interactive* shell with the user `user`. You're going to want to use the following:

```
su -c "cd \"$DEPLOYDIR\"; meteor build ." nodejs
```

Dissection:

`su`: `su` executable
`-c "COMMAND"`: run `COMMAND` as another user
`nodejs`: `nodejs` user